# How much does knife thickness matter?

Tags: equipment, knives

I was looking to buy myself a chef's knife, and was interested in either the Richardson Sheffield V Sabatier range, or their Sabatier Trompette range. Now, the latter is a bit cheaper, and the only difference I can see between the two is that one seems slightly thicker than the other. Neither is flimsy, but the V Sabatier's blade is about a millimeter thicker.

I am looking for a good quality knife that will last me, but I don't want to spend more money than is necessary. Is the extra thickness worth a ~£10 premium?

Comment: I would suggest handling them yourself before buying; the weight difference might be a selling point one way or the other.

Comment: @Max That would definitely be a good idea, but unfortunately since I live in a small town the only knives available here are those sold by Tesco, so unless I find myself going to London before I go to university, that won't be possible.

Comment: Add you comment you're going to uni, don't spend the extra because your knives aren't likely to get treated very well - you'll have more fun things to do than sharpen them often, and they'll get borrowed by other people. Plus you'll be learning your own preferences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extra thickness can be useful, but it can be quite annoying too.  We have some real knife experts here who will probably go into more detail, but as a kitchen amateur (using the sort of grade knife you're looking at) I tend to use a thinner knife for most things.  Much of what you use a knife for is slicing, and a thick knife adds nothing there. It can even mean that slices break or fall away before you're ready.

A thick, heavy knife is useful for various  things, like fine chopping at one extreme, or getting through a butternut squash at the other, but I wouldn't want to only have thick knives (my thickest knives are tucked away in the second knife block).